# Who is "quiet" when there is no comma?

Tags: commas

A stanza from Leslie Norris' poem **The Tiger:**

> He stalks in his vivid stripes
> The few steps of his cage,
> On pads of velvet **quiet,**
> In his quiet rage.

Who does the **quiet** belong to-- the velvet or the tiger?

Comment: My guess is it’s saying the tiger’s steps are quiet because its feet are as soft as velvet.

Comment: You are correct that strictly speaking with a comma 'quiet' would modify 'He', but without it the sense is that the "pads" are made of "velvet quiet".   However, this is poetic language, so it's not objectively or "strictly" one way or the other, really.  My personal sense is that it would be /terrible/ poetry if the tiger was "quiet, in his quiet rage".  So I'd say probably the pads are made of "velvet quiet".